# PHP if have image display image, if else text

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm a front-end web developer struggling with some theme option support. I am struggling to write a simple function in my header.php which allows me to do the following:

"if user uploads an image, use the image. If else use 'logo_text' and echo output. If user doesnt upload image or logo_text use default of 'My Site'"

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started? I don't know where to begin for this one.

```
    <li class="name">
      <!-- Logo Text -->
      <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <? $novus_logo_text = get_option('novus_logo_text'); echo $novus_logo_text; ?>
      </a></h1>
      <!-- Logo Image -->
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <? $novus_logo_upload = get_option('novus_logo_upload'); echo '<img class=\"logo"\ src="'.$novus_logo_upload.'" width=\"100%"\ />'; ?>
      </a>
    </li>
```

The code above works just fine. However if a client uses both the logo_text input and uploads a logo image they will both output. I need either or, with the image taking priority. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: I appreciate the quick response but again I am not PHP savy. Im the front-end graphics guy who can kinda piece together php. The above code I have + what I am trying to accomplish is kind of a brick wall for me right now. :P

Comment: `<?php if($novus_logo_upload = get_option('novus_logo_upload')){ //show logo } else { //show text}`? So if `$novus_logo_upload = get_option('novus_logo_upload')` returns `true` (ie. there is an image), then show the logo, else show the text.

Comment: Working on that solution now ^^^ give me a few. Thank you so much! Will append op post or comment if I am having issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really learn basic control structures even if your a front end guy, `if`, `while`, `for`, `foreach`, `switch`.

```
<li class="name">
  <?php if($novus_logo_upload = get_option('novus_logo_upload')){ ?>
  <!-- Logo Image -->
  <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <? echo '<img class=\"logo"\ src="'.$novus_logo_upload.'" width=\"100%"\ />'; ?>
  </a>
  <?php } else if($novus_logo_text = get_option('novus_logo_text')){ ?>
  <!-- Logo Text -->
  <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <? echo $novus_logo_text; ?>
  </a></h1>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <!-- Default -->
  <?php } ?>
</li>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much, it functions properly. It is something I am trying to learn but I started as a graphic designer, not a programmer. I do all right but I'm nowhere near this level of PHP yet. An example of my starter template (not developed as a 'theme' yet) can be made here: http://www.elevancement.com/novus-theme/

Comment: Ill use the PHP doc site to decipher the above code and learn what I need to. Thank you once again, this is very helpful.